# Using $match to query from different arrays with the same key value

Tags: mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have this simple JSON data of two documents both with two different arrays namely `carPolicies` and `paPolicies`. Within these arrays are objects named as `policy` where it contains a key 'agent' where the value is '47'.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "some_id"
    },
    "name": "qwe",
    "password": "pw",
    "carPolicies": [
        {
            "policy": { 
                "agent": "47"
            }
        },
        {
            "policy": {                   
                "agent": "47"
            }
        }
    ],
    "paPolicies": [
        {
            "policy": {                  
                "agent": "47"
            }
        },
        {
            "policy": {                   
                "agent": "47"
            }
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "some_id"
    },
    "name": "rty",
    "password": "wp",
    "carPolicies": [
        {
            "policy": { 
                "agent": "47"
            }
        },
        {
            "policy": {                   
                "agent": "47"
            }
        }
    ],
    "paPolicies": [
        {
            "policy": {                  
                "agent": "47"
            }
        },
        {
            "policy": {                   
                "agent": "47"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using mongoDB's $match operator, how do I come up with a query that if agent value is 47 in either arrays, it returns me the document's name?

This is what I currently have:

```
db.collection('users').aggregate([
    // Get just the docs that contain an agent element where agent is === req.params.name
    {$match: {$or: [{'paPolicies.policy.agent': req.params.name}, {'carPolicies.policy.agent': req.params.name}]} }, 
    {
        $project: {
            policy: {
                $filter: {
// how to do an 'or' operator at 'input' so it can be input: '$paPolicies.policy || $carPolicies.policy' 
                    input: '$paPolicies.policy',
                    as: 'police',
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$police.agent', req.params.name]}
                }
            },
            _id: 1, name: 1
        }
    }
])
```

I know that the above code is wrong but I feel like it's the closest I can currently get to a solution and hopefully gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get the requirement right. How about just using [`dot(.)` notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents) in a `.find()` query with [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-id-field) as second parameter.

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "carPolicies.policy.agent": "47"
    },
    {
      "paPolicies.policy.agent": "47"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": 1
})
```

Comment: Let me try this and I'll get back to you!

Comment: @BrioTech [Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GALjXYtwOZ0) check it out if thats what your are looking for.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Simple and clear cut. I might have been overthinking my problem after looking at your solution haha

Comment: Also, thanks for helping me discover mongo playground!